# Getting Issues while creating User

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app, user, dml

I am trying to create an User but I am getting error as follows:

> 18:46:26:307 FATAL_ERROR System.DmlException: Insert failed. 
>   First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, 
>   portal account owner must have a role: []

And when I try to fix above issue by providing a UserRoleId for the user which I want to create then getting issue as follows:

> FATAL_ERROR System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; 
>   first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, High Volume Portal Users cannot have a user role: Role ID: [UserRoleId]

In above cases the profile's userType is 'CspLitePortal'

And further, when I change the profile's userType to 'Standard' and try to create an User, the error I got is as follows:

> 18:41:40:576 FATAL_ERROR System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, only portal users can be associated to a contact: []

For my use case, I need to have contact Object associated with the User. Since Contact can have an attachement. My use case facilitates a photo upload for every user created. At the time of upload, I am storing the image base64 data as an attachment to that User's Contact record (which acts as Parent-Id for the attachment). We can't have an Attachment with User's record Id as parent-Id.
Any workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be creating the User using a User who has a Salesforce User license, not a Community or Portal User license. That Salesforce User should have a Role and would be the Account owner for the Contact you're creating for use in your Portal. Steps would be as follows:

If this is a TestClass, use RunAs. If it is production, a Portal User cannot create Users unless you have your code run in System Mode with an API User with a Role.

1. Create Account
2. Insert Account
3. Create Contact with AccountID from above
4. Insert Contact
5. Create User with ContactId from above
6. Insert User

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly describes your issue.

The role you are trying to assign should be for the Account owner, not the User.

When you create a contact, you have an account linked to the contact. Your Account linked to the contact will have an owner. The owner of the Account should have a role associated as per the error message.

Account --> Owner--> Role Assigned